# How to upload a file using Ajax in Scalajs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, scala, scala.js

I'm learning Scalajs by building an image sharing webapp.
In a form, I have a classic file input tag and would like to upload it using Ajax and jQuery to a remote server through a HTTP Post request.

This is the html:

```
<input id="postTitle" class="form-control" placeholder="Title" type="text" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">

<input id="file" class="form-control" placeholder="Browse" type="file" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">

<input id="tags" class="form-control" placeholder="Tags in format ['tag 1', 'tag 2',...]" type="text">

<button id="postButton" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
```

And here is the underlying Scala code:

```
lazy val submitElement = jQuery("#postButton")
jQuery(() => {
  submitElement.click {
    (_: JQueryEvent) => {
            dom.ext.Ajax.post(
          url = [server_url],
          data = ???, // <-- How do I get the file?
          headers = Map("Content-Type" -> "application/json")
        ).foreach { xhr =>
          if (xhr.status == 200) {
            val x = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)
            println(x)
          }
        }
    }
  }
})
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Refer [Scalajs Showcase Ajax example](https://github.com/hussachai/play-scalajs-showcase/blob/master/example-client/src/main/scala/common/ExtAjax.scala) for performing post methods in scalajs.

Extending the above example, you can write postAsFormData method and pass the uploaded file as a formData.

```
def postAsFormData(url: String,
     data: FormData,
     timeout: Int = 0,
     headers: Map[String, String] = Map.empty,
     withCredentials: Boolean = false) = {
        ajax.post( url, InputData.formdata2ajax(data), timeout,headers, withCredentials, "")
    }
```

Pass the file input as

```
val formData= new FormData()
formData.append("file",$("#fileInput").prop("files").item(0))
```

And then call the ajax postAsFormData method.

Answer (score 1):

I used FormData Api. It is doing with libs for scalajs https://github.com/scalajs-io/form-data

```
lazy val submitElement = jQuery("#postButton")

jQuery(() => {
  submitElement.click {
    (_: JQueryEvent) => {
       val file_data = jQuery('#file').prop("files")(0);   
       val form_data = FormData();                  
           form_data.append('file', file_data);

          dom.ext.Ajax.post(
          url = [server_url],
          data = form_data,
          headers = Map("Content-Type" -> "application/json")
        ).foreach { xhr =>
          if (xhr.status == 200) {
            val x = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)
            println(x)
          }
        }
    }
  }
})
```